# When is the localization of finitely generated $k$-algebra finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $B\cong k[T_1, \dots T_l]/J$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra which is possibly integral domain. $T_1 + J , \dots T_l + J$ are finite generators for $B$.

Let $S \subseteq B$ be any multiplicative closed set. I think that in general the finite typeness of $S^{-1}B$ over $k$ is false.

My question is, then how about the case that $S$ is of the form $S= \{ 1, g' , \dots, g'^{n} , \dots \}$ for some $g'\in B$? $B_{g'}$ is also finitely generated $k$-algebra? If so, then what whould be (finite) generators for $B_{g'}$? If this is also not true in general, then when?

**EDIT :** My first trial is as follows.

Let's denote $g' = g+ J$ for some $g\in R:=k[T_1, \dots T_l]$. Consider multiplicative closed set $D:=\{ 1,g ,g^2 ,\dots \}$ and its image $\bar{D} $ in $B= R/J$. Then we have $D^{-1}R/D^{-1}J \cong \bar{D}^{-1}(B=R/J) = B_{g'}$ ( C.f. [Localization commutes with quotient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630232/localization-commutes-with-quotient) ). Since $D^{-1}R = R_g = R[X]/(gX-1) = k[T_1,\dots T_l , X]/(gX-1)$ is finitely generated over $k$ and the homomorphic image of finitely generated algebra is itself finitely generated, $B_{g'}$ is finitely generated over $k$. And I guess that one of finite generators for $B_{g'}$ is $\{ (T_1 + (gX-1))+ D^{-1}J , \dots (T_l + (gX-1))+ D^{-1}J, (X + (gX-1))+ D^{-1}J \}$

True? Or is there more simpler form of generators?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes. You are right!. Thanks for pointing out. For now, I can't calculate $B_{g}=(k[t_1, \dots t_l]/J)[x]/(gx-1)$. What theorems may we use? And how can we find concrete generators? P.s. I think this is my first time seeing this kind of pattern.

Comment: O.K. I edited my question so that my first trial is included. True? Are my trial following your intentions well? Or is there more simpler choice of generators adapted to your intention ?

Comment: You must define an isomorphism $B_g \cong R:=B[t]/(tg-1)$. In the ring $R$ it follows the element $t$ has the property that $tg=1$, hence the element $g$ has an inverse in $R$. Are you familiar with the "universal property" of $B_g$? Can you use this property to define an isomorphism?

Comment: O.K. I will try to it. Thanks for pointing out~:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "Let's denote $g' = g+ J$ for some $g\in R:=k[T_1, \dots T_l]$. Consider multiplicative closed set $D:=\{ 1,g ,g^2 ,\dots \}$ and its image $\bar{D} $ in $B= R/J$. Then we have $D^{-1}R/D^{-1}J \cong \bar{D}^{-1}(B=R/J) = B_{g'}$ ( C.f. [Localization commutes with quotient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630232/localization-commutes-with-quotient) ). Since $D^{-1}R = R_g = R[X]/(gX-1) = k[T_1,\dots T_l , X]/(gX-1)$ is finitely generated over $k$ and the homomorphic image of finitely generated algebra is itself finitely generated, $B_{g'}$ is finitely generated over $k$. And I guess that one of finite generators for $B_{g'}$ is $\{ (T_1 + (gX-1))+ D^{-1}J , \dots (T_l + (gX-1))+ D^{-1}J, (X + (gX-1))+ D^{-1}J \}$

True? Or is there more simpler form of generators?

Can anyone help?"

**Answer:** Parts of this has been proved elsewhere on this site, here is another elementary and explicit proof of this fact that does not use the universal property of localization:

**Lemma:** There is an isomorphism of rings $R_g \cong A:=R[t]/(tg-1)$ for any $g\in R$.

**Proof** define a map $\phi': R[t] \rightarrow R_g$ by $\phi'(t):=1/g$. This map satisfies $\phi'(tg-1)=0$ hence we get an induced map $\phi: R[t]/(tg-1) \rightarrow R_g$. Define a map $\rho': R \rightarrow R[t]/(tg-1)$ by $\rho'(a):=a$. Since $tg=1$ in  $A$ it follows the element $g$ is a unit, hence there is (by the universal property of localization) a canonical map $\rho: R_g \rightarrow A$. Let us define this explicitly and prove it is well defined.

Define $\rho(a/g^n):=at^n$. If $a/g^n \cong b/g^m$ there is an integer $k\geq 0$ with

$$  g^{k+m}a = g^{k+n}b $$

in $R$. Using $\rho$ we get a similar equality in $A$. Since $g$  is a unit in $A$ it
follows

$$  t^k g^{k+m}a= t^k g^{k+n}b $$

hence ( in $A$ )

$$ g^m a = g^n b.$$

we get

$$t^m g^m a = t^m g^n b$$

hence $a=g^nt^m b$.

We get

$$t^n a= t^ng^n t^m b=t^mb$$

and it follows $\rho(a/g^n)=t^na=t^mb=\rho(b/g^n)$.

Hence the map is well defined. You may check $\rho$ and $\phi$ are inverses of each other and it follows $\rho$ is an isomorphism of rings.

Hence for any ring $R$ and any element $g\in R$ it follows $R_g$ is a fintely generated $R$-algebra since $R_g \cong R[t]/(tg-1)$ is generated by one element $\overline{t}$.

As mentioned in the comments: If $R:=k[t]$ and if $S:=R-\{(0)\}$ it follows $S^{-1}(R) \cong k(x)$ is not a finitely generated $R$-algebra for the following reason:

Assume there is a finite set of generators $f_i/g_i \in k(x)$ for $i=1,..,n$. Let $g:=\prod g_i, g(i):=g/g_i$. It follows $f_i/g_i=F_i/g$ with $F_i:=f_ig(i)$.  Let $h$ be a polynomial that is relatively prime to $g$. A linear combination

$$ \sum_i a_i(f_i/g_i) =(\sum_i a_iF_i)/g $$

can never equal $1/h$ since $g$ and $h$ are relatively prime. Hence $k(x)$ does not have a finite set of generators over $k[x]$.

@Plantation - you should always define maps between commutative rings "constructively". This means if $A:=k[x_1,..,x_n]/I$ is the quotient of a polynomial ring in a finite set of variables $x_i$  by an ideal $I:=(h_1,..,h_l)$, a map of k-algebras $f:A \rightarrow B$ is defined by giving a set of elements $f(x_i):=b_i \in B$, such that for any element $h \in I$ it follows $h(b_i)=0$ for all $h \in I$.

By this I mean the following: A map $f$ induce a map

$$F: k[x_1,..,x_n] \rightarrow B$$

defined by $F(x_i):=b_i \in B$. Since the map $F$ sends the ideal $I$ to zero in $B$ it follows

$$(*) F(h_j(x_1,..,x_n)):=h_j(b_1,..,b_n)=0$$

for the generators $h_1,..,h_l$ of the ideal $I$.
Hence you must define a map $F$ such that the equations $(*)$ are fulfilled.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151003/discussion-on-answer-by-hm2020-when-is-the-localization-of-finitely-generated-k); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.